# Merging one-dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I want to merge those three arrays:

```
array (
  [0] => zooey,
  [1] => Robert,
  [2] => james,
  [3] => Alfred,
);
array (
  [0] => city1,
  [1] => city2,
  [2] => city3,
  [3] => city4,
);
array (
  [1] => city1,
  [2] => city2,
  [3] => city3,
  [4] => city4,
);
```

into this:

```
array (
  [0] => array('id'=>user_id1,'name'=>username1, 'city'=>user city1),
  [1] => array('id'=>user_id2,'name'=>username2, 'city'=>user city2),
  // and so on
);
```

Comment: Can you share what you've attempted?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php

Comment: @JayBlanchard I've used `array_merge()` and `array_combine()` . At first it give me some hope but after several tries , I still can't do it

Comment: hey there. Grouping your array and properly formatting them helps understanding right away what you want. Be as straightforward as you can. We would like to see (as in edit the code in your question) what you have actually tried to merge the arrays, and where it failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your own merge function ,if all 3 arrays are same size with correct positioning of relevant elements, the function would look like this

```
function combineUserArray($arrayNames, $arrayCities, $arrayIds){
    $users = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayIds); $i++){
        $users[$i] = [
            'id'=>$arrayIds[$i],
            'name'=>$arrayNames[$i],
            'city'=>$arrayCities[$i],
        ];
    } 
    return $users;
}
```

Comment: perhaps `;` should be replaced by `,` ? it gives an error.